# Parameters for calculating accuracy of part of speech tagger

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, pos-tagger

I'm a beginner in Natural Language Processing, and I've this basic question about calculating the accuracy of a POS Tagger (tagger is using a corpus):

(Don't confuse the word 'set' below with the mathematical definition of set. I'm just using it as a normal English word to convey some 'group' or 'mapping' )

There are different metrics of accuracy like Precision/Recall and Confusion matrix. Both of these require the following two things as input parameter:
***1.*** *Predicted Result set* : After the POS Tagger runs on the input, we have a prediction of tags for the input words. This parameter I understand; it's basically what the tagger generated using the corpus and some statistical techniques. This set is our *prediction*
***2.*** *Actual Result set* : This set represents what the *actual* tag of each word is supposed to be. This set is the *reality*.
**My question is about this second parameter:** How is this set supposed to be "constructed". Am I supposed to manually construct a set that maps each input word to the **correct** tag?. By manually, I mean reading the corpus and then finding what the corresponding tag is for each input word.

***So my question basically is:*** If there's some code that calculates accuracy of a POS-Tagger, what is the accuracy calculated against? How does this code know what is the correct mapping of words to tags? And if it does know the correct mapping of words to tags then why is *this* code not being used to do the tagging itself? (I hope the reader understands my confusion here).

I'll give this example:
**Input sentence** : I am a boy.
**Predicted Tags** : I_Pronoun am_Noun a_Article boy_Verb. (simplified names for tags, and obviously the tagging has been done wrong)

**Actual tagging should be** : I_Pronoun am_Verb a_Article boy_Noun
*I* know what the tagging should be, *but* how does the accuracy calculator code know what the actual tagging should be? Am I supposed manually prepare a mapping of correct tags for each input sentence, and then pass it as a parameter?

Note that I know how the calculation for Precision/Recall works. I'm simply asking: *how do I tell it what's the correct tagging set* ?

Comment: You're right: you need to "manually" prepare the word-tag mapping. This is usually done by separating a part of the corpus (at least 20%) as test data and not using it for training. Also note, that in the case of POS tagging precision and recall are the same, so you can speak of just accuracy.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin Why are precision and recall the same? I didn't understand.. I think each tag would have a different precision/recall (with precision and recall being different). It's just like all other classifications which will have different counts of True Positive, False Positive, False Negative..right? I'm going to do TAGWISE precision-recall..

Comment: if you count for each tag, then yes, precision/recall would be different, but if you count an aggregate metric it will be the same, because you have `N` points you need to predict and if you get `M` right than your precision is `M/N` - and for recall you have `N` suggestions and you get the same `M` right so it's also `M/N`

Answer (score 1):

As said Vsevolod Dyomkin, if you wish to test your program, you'll need to have pre-labeled data corresponding to reality. You may either create your own manually or use an available one, like the [brown corpus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Corpus). Since one of your tag is `scikit-learn`, I'll assume you're using NLTK, which enables you to use it directly via `nltk.download()`.

While I'm not aware of implementations details, once you dispose of both the predicted and actual sets, you should be able to use the provided functions of scikit-learn, such as [`confusion_matrix`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix). For instance,

```
predicted_tags = ['NOUN', 'VERB']
real_tags = ['NOUN', 'PRONOUN']
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
```

will return

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```