# Get tag-specific accuracy for pos tagger in spacy tagger evaluation

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, pos-tagger

I'm using the code below for evaluate the pos tagger that I trained in `spacy 2.3.0` (built from source- last commit : `9860b8399ed2a3d1d680e1c1cd31d85926422709`):

```
  def evaluate(nlp, examples):
    scorer = Scorer()
    nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)
    for input_, annot in examples:
        doc_gold_text = nlp.make_doc(input_)
        gold = GoldParse(doc_gold_text, tags=annot['tags'])
        pred_value = nlp(input_)
        scorer.score(pred_value, gold)
    return scorer.scores


def main(model='model'):
    test_data = train_data_getter()[80000:]
    nlp = spacy.load(model)
    # nlp = None
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
    pp.pprint(evaluate(nlp, test_data))
```

and the result is:

```
 {'ents_f': 0.0,
 'ents_p': 0.0,
 'ents_per_type': {},
 'ents_r': 0.0,
 'las': 0.0,
 'las_per_type': {'': {'f': 0.0, 'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0}},
 'tags_acc': 88.9152111081426,
 'textcat_score': 0.0,
 'textcats_per_cat': {},
 'token_acc': 100.0,
 'uas': 0.0}
```

I wonder if there is a way to get accuracy per every part-of-speech tag?

Comment: this may [help : Parameters for calculating accuracy of part of speech tagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100559/parameters-for-calculating-accuracy-of-part-of-speech-tagger)

Comment: @sahasrara62 thank you! the question you linked is a general question about evaluating pos-taggers. I need to know if spacy itself contains a tag specific evaluator.

Comment: i guess you need to see the documentation or else you can raise this as an issue in spacy github pannel as this is some feature related request,